# setting property as function in a constructor javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

i'm working with a piece of code that sets a name property as a function

```
name = n;  
  this.name = function(n){
    if( n ) name=n;
    return name;
  }
```

full constructor is:

```
function Warrior(n){
  name = n;  
  this.name = function(n){
    if( n ) name=n;
    return name;
  }
}
```

I don't understand how this is different than this.name = n; and why I can't use that in a toString function like

```
Person.prototype.toString = function(){
    return "Hi! my name's "+this.name;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

What you created is a getter/setter for `name`:

1. A getter is a function which returns a value associated with an object property.
2. A setter is a function which updates the value associated with an object property.

Getters and setters are useful for creating “derived properties” (i.e. properties which are derived from other properties). For example:

```js
function Person(firstname, lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

Person.prototype.fullname = function (fullname) {
    if (arguments.length < 1) return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
    var newname = fullname.split(" ");
    this.firstname = newname[0];
    this.lastname = newname[1];
    return fullname;
};

var person = new Person("Aadit", "Shah");

alert(person.firstname);
alert(person.lastname);
alert(person.fullname());

person.fullname("Chuck Norris");

alert(person.firstname);
alert(person.lastname);
alert(person.fullname());
```

In the above code `fullname` is a derived property. It is derived from `firstname` and `lastname`. As you can see, when I update `fullname`, I am also updating `firstname` and `lastname`. Hence getters and setters are useful in this case.

However a lot of people misuse getters and setters. For example:

```
function Warrior(name) {
    this.name = function (newName) {
        if (arguments.length >= 1)
            name = newName;
        return name;
    }
}
```

In this case there's no good reason to create a getter/setter for name because it is not a derived property. It's a misuse of getters/setters and all it does is make the code slower. Instead it should be implemented as:

```
function Warrior(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Plain and simple.

---

Now consider:

```
Person.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "Hi! my name's " + this.name;
};
```

The reason this doesn't work is because `this.name` is a getter function. Hence you need to call it to get the actual value. Thus, it should be:

```
Person.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "Hi! my name's " + this.name();
};
```

---

Finally, newer versions of JavaScript have built in support for getters and setters:

```js
function Person(firstname, lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "fullname", {
    get: function () {
        return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
    },
    set: function (fullname) {
        var newname = fullname.split(" ");
        this.firstname = newname[0];
        this.lastname = newname[1];
    }
});

var person = new Person("Aadit", "Shah");

alert(person.firstname);
alert(person.lastname);
alert(person.fullname);

person.fullname = "Chuck Norris";

alert(person.firstname);
alert(person.lastname);
alert(person.fullname);
```

This makes getters and setters look like normal properties. Such properties are called accessor properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here your constructor function is `Warrior` and you can add new method `toString` to an existing prototype `Warrior`. Like this you can add.

```
Warrior.prototype.toString = function(){ // code goes here }
```

`this.name` is a function .so

```
Warrior.prototype.toString = function(){
     return "Hi! my name's "+this.name();
}
```

Using `new` keyword to create new objects from the same prototype

```
Warrior.prototype.toString = function(){
    return "Hi! my name's "+this.name();
}
myname = new Warrior("ur name");
console(myname.toString());
```